# Electron won't spawn flask-socketio server: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, electron, flask-socketio

I am roughly following [this](https://www.fyears.org/2017/02/electron-as-gui-of-python-apps-updated.html) and [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) to embed a flask server into an electron project. If I `flask run` the server then `electron .`, the connection is established. However, if I try to initialize the server during electron startup, the server never starts (or something I don't really know much about) and I continue to get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I have tried to clear my cache and DNS flush as well (thinking the problem might be local). Any direction on what I can do here?

P.S. This is my first real adventure with JS, I am mainly a Python guy. Sorry for bad syntax.

UPDATE: Don't have the rep to reply @Miguel, I use `conda env` and yes it is activated prior to launch. Furthermore, with the environment variables set, I have successfully booted the server using `python -m flask run`, `flask run`, and `python .\scripts\Backend\testFlask.py`.  Spawning any of these methods within Electron is causing the same connection error.

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog} = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win
let server;
process.env.FLASK_APP = '.\\scripts\\Backend\\testFlask.py';
process.env.FLASK_DEBUG = 1;

module.exports = {
    openFile: function () {
        var files = dialog.showOpenDialog({
            properties: ['openFile']
        });

        if (!files) { return; }

        var file = files[0];
        console.log(typeof file)
        var content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();

        win.webContents.send('fileOpener', file, content);
        console.log(content);
    }
};

function createWindow(){
    const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: width * (2/3),
        height: height * (9/10),
        show: false
        })

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }))

    win.once('ready-to-show', ()=> {
        win.show();
    })

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    })
}

app.on('ready', function(){
    var script = path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'Backend', 'testFlask.py')
    server = require('child_process').spawn('python.exe', [script])
    server.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString())
    })

    createWindow()
    const applicationMenu = require('./menu');
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(applicationMenu);
    })

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win == null) {
        createWindow();
        const applicationMenu = require('./menu');
        Menu.setApplicationMenu(applicationMenu);
    }
})
```

testFlask.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet'test)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    print('Welcome')

@socketio.on('message')
def data_received(message):
    print(message)
    send(message)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connection():
    print('Echelon connection established')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("testing")
    socketio.run(app, port='8080', debug=True)
```

socketAPI.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log(socket.connected) //make sure the connection is established
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message + ' received');
    });

    $('form#searchBarForm').submit(function(event) {
        console.log(event.target["0"].value + ' sent') //for debugging
        socket.send(event.target["0"].value);
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv? If yes, is it activated when you start your JS script? Also you said you manually start the Python server with `flask run`, but use `python scripts/Backend/testFlask.py` from JS. Does this last start up method work when you do it from the command-line? Or vice-versa, does the JS start up work better if you use `flask run`?

Comment: @Miguel, I updated my question. However, after getting frustrated and turning off my computer for the weekend, it seems to connect now...puzzling, but fixed (I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that a hard reboot of my computer fixed the issue. Something beyond the cache and DNS was causing issues. Upon coming back to it after the weekend, a stable connection was established. Thank you @Miguel